# How to use Except clause in Bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

I am trying to use the existing `Except` clause in Bigquery. Please find my query below

```
select * EXCEPT (b.hosp_id, b.person_id,c.hosp_id) from 
person a 
inner join hospital b
on a.hosp_id= b.hosp_id
inner join reading c
on a.hosp_id= c.hosp_id
```

As you can see I am using 3 tables. All the 3 tables have the `hosp_id` column, so I would like to remove duplicate columns which are `b.hosp_id` and `c.hosp_id`. Simlarly, I would like to remove `b.person_id` column as well.

When I execute the above query, I get the syntax error as shown below

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got "." at [9:19]
```

Please note that all the columns that I am using in `Except` clause is present in the tables used. Additional info is all the tables used are **temp tables created using `with` clause**. When I do the same manually by selecting column of interest, it works fine. But I have several columns and can't do this manually.

Can you help? I am trying to learn Bigquery. Your inputs would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead:

```sql
select * EXCEPT (person_id) from 
person a 
inner join hospital b
using (hosp_id)
inner join reading c
using (hosp_id)
```

You can only put column names (not paths) in the EXCEPT list, and you can simply avoid projecting the duplicate columns with USING instead of ON.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. Will try..Upvoted. By path, do you mean alias?

Comment: I tried without alias for a column (ex - instead of `c.reading_number`, I just used `reading_number` and it works. Can bigquery automatically identify the source table of that column mentioned?

Comment: By path I mean something of the form `a.b` with a dot in between names.

Answer (score 8):

I use the `EXCEPT` on a per-table basis:

```
select p.* EXCEPT (hosp_id, person_id),
       h.*,
       r.* EXCEPT (hosp_id)
from person p inner join
     hospital h
     on p.hosp_id = h.hosp_id inner join
     reading r
     on p.hosp_id = r.hosp_id;
```

Note that this also uses *meaningful* abbreviations for table aliases, which makes the query much simpler to understand.

In your case, I don't think you need `EXCEPT` at all if you use the `USING` clause.

Comment: Good to know this approach as well. Upvoted. Thank you.